# Creating Command Button and adding pre-written code to it

Tags: excel, vba

I need a VBA code for the following condition in office 2010

I am making a template for report generation where template is saved in .xls format.eg. shift_A.xls
After a specific interval, task schedular will run that template, and will save it by some other name in .xlsx format eg.Shift_A_26-Nov.xlsx

Now i need a macro which will create a "close command button" into newly generated file i.e.Shift_A_26-Nov.xlsx, and will write code ("application.close")in to it automatically.
i do have code to save that template with other name but need a code to create "close command button" and write a code in to it.

Please help me regarding this issue.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim projname As String
Dim timestamp As String
Dim mypath As String
Dim myfilename As String
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim temptimestamp As String

Sub autorun()
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    projname = "SHIFT_A"
    temptimestamp = Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Text
    dateformat
    For Each Ws In Sheets
        Ws.Activate
        copy_pastevalues
    Next Ws

    Worksheets(1).Select
    Range("A1").Select
    mypath = "C:\IA REPORT ARCH\SHIFT_A"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=mypath + "\" + timestamp + "_" + projname, 
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    APPLICATION.QUIT

End Sub

Sub dateformat()
    timestamp = Format(temptimestamp, "dd-mmm-yy")
End Sub

Sub copy_pastevalues()
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

This is the that i am using for autosave that report template

Comment: Please help us help you, by showing what you've already tried.

Comment: I have attached a code that i am using for auto generation of my report..now a need  to add a close button and its code, automatically into newly generated file

Comment: Is the code for the Close button anything more than just "close" or is it supposed to perform some other tasks?

Comment: BTW, the easy way is to add that button, create the new xls from that 'template' and make button visible only if/when

Comment: After clicking that button..the application should close

Comment: Please understand my problem clearly. ..i need to add a macro in .xls file whoch will create a close button and its code in .xlsx file which will be output of the template file

Answer (score 0):

You can't save a macro in a .xlsx file. You need .xlsm, so replace

FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

with

FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled